# Can't add Jackson libraries to my android project

Tags: android, jar, jackson, eclipse-adt

I  want to use Jackson JSON 2.1.1 parser in my Android project in Eclipse ADT. I've downloaded Jackson jar files (annotations, databind,core). And added them as external jars to the project  and even include them in order and export:

[image]

[image]

I see these jars in referenced libraries, but I can't import and use them: import org.codehaus.jackson is't seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a "libs" folder in your project root and dropping the jars in there. Android handles this by convention. You won't need to explicitly add them to your build path.

If that doesn't work, make sure you've downloaded the correct jars.

And when all else fails:
Refresh and/or Project -> Clean and/or quit and restart Eclipse

:)

Answer (score 0):

use: 
 
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper